# add data item to observablecollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

I need to add selected items to this collection..
I select my item on a page and then appbar appears and i want on the appbar button tapped event to add item to collection that will be displayed on the other page..

```
private void Button_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        AllActors m = new AllActors();

        ActorsObject objkt = itemGridView.SelectedItem;

        m.allActors.Add(objkt);

    }
```

this doesnt work... here are my classes:

```
public class AllActors : LivingDataCommon
{ 
public AllActors()
        : base(String.Empty, String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public AllActors(String ID, String title)
        : base(ID, title)
    { }

    private ObservableCollection<ActorsObject> _AllActors = new ObservableCollection<ActorsObject>();
    public ObservableCollection<ActorsObject> allActors
    {
        get { return this._AllActors; }
    }

}
```

Comment: "this doesn't work" isn't helpful. In what way doesn't it work? Is an exception thrown? Does it run okay but doesn't do what you expect? What have you tried?

Comment: this pops out:Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'LivingAutomation.Data.ActorsObject'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: It will also tell you what line is causing that error. That should be enough for you to work out what's going on (and how to fix it) for yourself, but I'll add an answer shortly to explain...

Answer (score 3):

**Problem one: compiler error "Cannot implicitly convert type"**

```
ActorsObject objkt = itemGridView.SelectedItem;
```

The GridView's SelectedItem property returns an object. You're trying to assign that to a variable of type ActorsObject, and the compiler can't assume that this is okay. You have to tell it...

```
ActorsObject objkt = (ActorsObject)itemGridView.SelectedItem;
```

The compiler's error message specifically asked "are you missing a cast?" and pointed to this line. That's useful information - it's just told you what was wrong and suggested how to fix it. Always read compiler errors and think about what they're telling you, don't just reduce it to "it doesn't work".

---

**Problem two: "it doesn't do what I want"**

```
private void Button_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AllActors m = new AllActors();
        ActorsObject objkt = itemGridView.SelectedItem;
        m.allActors.Add(objkt);
    }
```

Read this carefully and think about what it's doing. On the first line of the function, you're creating a new AllActors object and assign it to 'm'. On the third line, you make a change to that object. But then your function ends, and you've thrown that object away!

It's more likely that to achieve what you want you need to create the AllActors object as a field on your window class. Then you can keep the object around, bind to it, and any changes to it will be kept. Something like this, although you will also need some UI to display this data.

```
private AllActors _m = new AllActors();

private void Button_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ActorsObject objkt = (ActorsObject)itemGridView.SelectedItem;
        _m.allActors.Add(objkt);
    }
```

Comment: (1) what do you need it to do? (2) what is it doing instead? (3) does it compile okay? if not, what error message are you given? (4) does it throw an exception? if so, what exception and where is it thrown? Information like this is important. If your compiler or program is giving you information, don't ignore it. If you don't understand it, at least give it to us to help us to help you. Nobody here is psychic.

Comment: now this line doesnt do what i need it to do..

`m.allActors.Add(objkt);`


i need it to add that selected object to allActors ObsevableCollection, I need to put the code in so I can use this collection as data source on my Home.xaml page.. this code is not working:
`var allactors = AllActors();
            
            this.DefaultViewModel["Group"] = allactors;
            this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = allactors.allActors;`

Comment: code is compiling well, but still my page is empty when i enter it after clicking on the button where my function is.. i dont know where the problem might be.. sry I am new at c# windows8 programing..

Comment: This is happening because you're not keeping your AllActors object around when the function ends - you throw it away at the end of the function. You need to store it in a variable elsewhere so that it's kept when the function ends.

Comment: Can I create just an empty ObservableCollection<ActorsObject> and use this collection to put my selected items in. Then call the same collection on the other page as data source. I have Page.xaml and Home.xaml, I need selected items from Page.xaml to be displayed in Home.xaml, my Page.xaml is populated with Items that are ActorObjects, and my Home.xaml is empty untill i add items to it using the appbar button on the Page.xaml

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
ActorsObject objkt = itemGridView.SelectedItem;
```

to

```
ActorsObject objkt = (ActorsObject)itemGridView.SelectedItem;
```

you are missing a cast there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ActorsObject objkt = (ActorsObject ) itemGridView.SelectedItem;
m.allActors.Add(objkt);
```

or

```
ActorsObject objkt = itemGridView.SelectedItem as ActorsObject;
m.allActors.Add(objkt);
```

You have to cast SelectedItem, since it is `object` not `ActorsObject`